# When a package is removed all package files should be removed?

Tags: laravel

To remove a package using the command "composer remove vendor/vendor" it works, the command dont shows any error. However the package files (classes, etc) are not removed from the folder of the project. Its necessary to remove manually the package fiels that are not removed with the remove command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if you want to remove them from your disk.

If you are running in developer mode, i think that has no problem to let them there, because when you go to deploy your project a new fresh installation script will run with the information of your `composer.json`, if in your `composer.json` file don't have any entry with the 'vendor/package' which you want to remove, it will not be installed.

Commonly composer removes any packages that aren't in your `composer.json` package list fom the vendor folder.

Comment: With one (or more) caveat ftp deployment to shared host.